# How to input several values in one line in haskell

Tags: haskell

For example, I want to write a program which will take 3 integers as input from command line. The functions I have learned is `readLn` to read values from entire line. But `readLn` seems to parse the entire line as a single value. How can I get the three values of one line with haskell?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Read a line with `getLine`, split it into `words`, and `read` each:

```
readInts :: IO [Int]
readInts = fmap (map read.words) getLine
```

it reads any number of Ints:

```
ghci> readInts
1 2 3
[1,2,3]
ghci> readInts
1 2 3 4 5 6
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

You could restrict to three:

```
read3Ints :: IO [Int]
read3Ints = do
     ints <- readInts
     if length ints == 3 then return ints else do
         putStrLn ("sorry, could you give me exactly three integers, "
                  ++ "separated by spaces?")
         read3Ints
```

which looks like this:

```
ghci> read3Ints
1 2
sorry, could you give me exactly three integers, separated by spaces?
1 23 , 5, 6
sorry, could you give me exactly three integers, separated by spaces?
1,2,3
sorry, could you give me exactly three integers, separated by spaces?
1 3 6
```

---

### The secrets of `fmap`

`fmap` works a bit like `map`, but you can use it more widely:

```
ghci> fmap (*10) [1,2,3,4]
[10,20,30,40]
ghci> fmap (*10) (Just 5)
Just 50
ghci> map (fmap (*10)) [Left 'b', Right 4, Left 'c', Right 7]
[Left 'b',Right 40,Left 'c',Right 70]
ghci> fmap words getLine
Hello there me hearties!
["Hello","there","me","hearties!"]
```

In `getInts`, I did `fmap (map read.words)` to split the line by spaces, then `map read` to turn each one into an `Int`. The compiler knows I wanted `Int` because of the type signature - I'd get an error if I omitted it.

Answer (score 2):

There several ways you could go about this, but I'd prefer the one using `reads`.  This function has type `Read a => ReadS a`, where `ReadS a` is just a type alias for `String -> [(a, String)]`.  It pulls characters from the provided string, stopping when it no longer successfully parses, then returns a list containing a tuple of the parsed value and the remaining string.  It uses a list for a more flexible definition, but in practice you'll never see it return a list more than 1 element.  An example would be

```
> reads "1 2 3" :: [(Int, String)]
[(1, " 2 3")]
> reads " 2 3" :: [(Int, String)]
[(2, " 3")]
```

Using this function, we can parse a line for `Int`s and it'll automatically stop when it fails to parse one or the string is empty.  We just need a way to chain together multiple calls.  Ideally, we'd like a function with the type `(s -> [(a, s)]) -> s -> [a]` so that we can re-use it:

```
chain :: (s -> [(a, s)]) -> s -> [a]
chain f s = case f s of
    [] -> []
    [(a, newS)] -> a : chain f newS
    xs -> map fst xs ++ chain f (last $ map snd xs)
```

Then you can use it as

```
> chain reads "1 2 3" :: [Int]
[1, 2, 3]
> chain reads "1 2 3 asdf" :: [Int]
[1, 2, 3]
> chain reads "asdf 1 2 3" :: [Int]
[]
```

Then you just have to do

```
read3Ints :: String -> [Int]
read3Ints = take 3 . chain reads
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
    getInts::[Int]
    getInts = do s<-getLine
                 map read . words $ s
```

Comment: try type checking this